# Scene Service - Access Denied in Runtime App

Tags: arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I cannot get a Scene Service to load into my Runtime app. It is a simple app with a scene and a Layer list. It is 99% the same as the code in the "[Token Authentication Challenge](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/sample-code/tokensecuredchallenge.htm)" sample app. I have changed the XAML to display a SceneView and my Scene-Service using an ArcGISSceneLayer layer. The topo layer displays as 'Access Granted' however my layer shows 'Access Denied'. I am using ArcGIS Runtime 100.0 and Visual Studio 2013. Whilst rejigging the code I also saw the error 'key not found'. That code is further below ('XAML 2' and 'C# 2').

**Code below:**

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TokenSecuredServices.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:esri="http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/runtime/2013"
    Title="Token Secured Services (Challenge)">

<Grid x:Name="layoutGrid">
    <esri:SceneView x:Name="MySceneView">
        <esri:Scene>
            <!-- This layer is public and does not require credentials -->
            <esri:ArcGISTiledLayer Name="World Street Map - Public"
                Source="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer" />
            <!-- This layer is secured with ArcGIS tokens and requires a login -->
            <!--username: user1 | password: user1-->
            <esri:ArcGISSceneLayer Name="AGOL Scene Service"
                Source="https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/*********/arcgis/rest/services/*********/SceneServer" />
        </esri:Scene>
    </esri:SceneView>

    <!-- Login UI -->
    <Border x:Name="loginPanel"
            Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" 
            Margin="30" Padding="20"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                       Margin="0,0,0,8"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       Text="{Binding ServiceUrl, StringFormat='Login to: {0}'}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                       Margin="0,0,0,8"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       Text="Username and Password are user1/user1" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" 
                       Margin="2" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       Text="Username" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
                     Margin="2" 
                     Text="{Binding UserName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" 
                       Margin="2" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       Text="Password" />
            <!-- For simplicity, the password is visible in this example. You can use a PasswordBox to mask the password text,
                 but it complicates data binding. See this discussion for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483892/how-to-bind-to-a-passwordbox-in-mvvm -->
            <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" 
                     Margin="2" 
                     Text="{Binding Password, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                    Margin="0,12,0,0" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    Content="Login and Load Layer" 
                    IsDefault="True"
                    Click="LoginButtonClick" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                       Margin="8,12,8,0" 
                       Foreground="Red" 
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       Text="{Binding ErrorMessage}">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ErrorMessage}" Value="">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <!-- Layer listing with status -->
    <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" 
            Margin="30" 
            MaxWidth="500"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"
                       Margin="4" 
                       Text="Map Layers (with status)" />
            <ListView x:Name="listLayerStatus" 
                      Padding="6" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MySceneView, Path=Scene.AllLayers}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,5" 
                                           FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <TextBlock.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LoadStatus}" 
                                                             Value="2">
                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Access Denied" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LoadStatus}" Value="0">
                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Access Granted" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>

                                            <Style.Setters>
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Initializing" />
                                            </Style.Setters>
                                        </Style>
                                    </TextBlock.Style>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
using Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Security;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace TokenSecuredServices
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // Task completion source to track a login attempt
        private TaskCompletionSource<Credential> _loginTaskCompletionSource;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Define a method to challenge the user for credentials when a secured resource is encountered
            AuthenticationManager.Current.ChallengeHandler = new ChallengeHandler(Challenge);
        }

        private async Task<Credential> Challenge(CredentialRequestInfo info)
        {
            // Call code to get user credentials
            // Make sure it runs on the UI thread
            if (this.Dispatcher == null)
            {
                // No current dispatcher, code is already running on the UI thread
                return await GetUserCredentialsFromUI(info);
            }
            else
            {
                // Use the dispatcher to invoke the challenge UI
                return await this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => GetUserCredentialsFromUI(info));
            }
        }

        private async Task<Credential> GetUserCredentialsFromUI(CredentialRequestInfo info)
        {
            // Show the login UI
            try
            {
                // Create a new LoginInfo to store the entered username and password
                // Pass the CredentialRequestInfo object so the resource URI can be stored
                var loginInputInfo = new LoginInfo(info);

                // Set the login UI data context with the LoginInfo
                loginPanel.DataContext = loginInputInfo;

                // Show the login UI
                loginPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                // Create a new task completion source to return the user's login when complete
                // Set the login UI data context (LoginInfo object) as the AsyncState so it can be retrieved later
                _loginTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Credential>(loginPanel.DataContext);

                // Return the task from the completion source
                // When the login button on the UI is clicked, the info will be returned for creating the credential
                return await _loginTaskCompletionSource.Task;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Hide the login UI
                loginPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        // Handle the click event for the login button on the login UI
        private async void LoginButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Make sure there's a task completion source for the login operation
            if (_loginTaskCompletionSource == null || _loginTaskCompletionSource.Task == null || _loginTaskCompletionSource.Task.AsyncState == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Get the login info from the task completion source
            var loginEntry = _loginTaskCompletionSource.Task.AsyncState as LoginInfo;

            try
            {
                // Create a token credential using the provided username and password
                TokenCredential userCredentials = await AuthenticationManager.Current.GenerateCredentialAsync
                                            (new Uri(loginEntry.ServiceUrl),
                                             loginEntry.UserName,
                                             loginEntry.Password,
                                             loginEntry.RequestInfo.GenerateTokenOptions);

                // Set the result on the task completion source
                _loginTaskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(userCredentials);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Show exceptions on the login UI
                loginEntry.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;

                // Increment the login attempt count
                loginEntry.AttemptCount++;

                // Set an exception on the login task completion source after three login attempts
                if (loginEntry.AttemptCount >= 3)
                {
                    // This causes the login attempt to fail
                    _loginTaskCompletionSource.TrySetException(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Helper class to contain login information
    internal class LoginInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // Information about the current request for credentials 
        private CredentialRequestInfo _requestInfo;
        public CredentialRequestInfo RequestInfo
        {
            get { return _requestInfo; }
            set
            {
                _requestInfo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        // URI for the service that is requesting credentials
        private string _serviceUrl;
        public string ServiceUrl
        {
            get { return _serviceUrl; }
            set
            {
                _serviceUrl = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        // Username entered by the user
        private string _userName;
        public string UserName
        {
            get { return _userName; }
            set
            {
                _userName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        // Password entered by the user
        private string _password;
        public string Password
        {
            get { return _password; }
            set
            {
                _password = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        // Last error message encountered while creating credentials
        private string _errorMessage;
        public string ErrorMessage
        {
            get { return _errorMessage; }
            set
            {
                _errorMessage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        // Number of login attempts
        private int _attemptCount;
        public int AttemptCount
        {
            get { return _attemptCount; }
            set
            {
                _attemptCount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        // Store the credential request information when the class is constructed
        public LoginInfo(CredentialRequestInfo info)
        {
            RequestInfo = info;
            ServiceUrl = info.ServiceUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
            ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
            AttemptCount = 0;
        }

        // Raise a property changed event so bound controls can update
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML 2:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Scene_Layer_Test.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                  xmlns:esri="http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/runtime/2013" 
                  Title="MainWindow"
                  WindowState="Maximized"
                  xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Scene_Layer_Test"
                  Height="573"
                  Width="789.375"
                  x:Name="SceneWindow">
<Grid Background="Black" Margin="0,0,0,11">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="461*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="320*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="247*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="99*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <esri:SceneView Margin="10" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="3" Name="MySceneView" />

    <Button x:Name="LoadSFBuildings" Content="Load New Scene" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Click="LoadNewScene_Click" Grid.Column="1" Height="27"/>
    <Label Content="New Scene Load Status: " Name="LoadStatusLabel"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Width="179" Foreground="White" Height="29"/>
    <TextBlock Text="No Scene Available Yet" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="194,5,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="215" Height="24" Foreground="White" Name="LoadStatusTextBlock"/>
    <Button x:Name="LoadAuckLayer" Content="Load LAS Scene Service" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191" Click="LoadAuckLayer_Click" Height="27"/>
    <Label Content="Scene Service Load Status: " x:Name="LoadStatusLabel_Copy"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,34,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Width="179" Foreground="White" Height="29"/>
    <TextBlock Text="No Layer Available Yet" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="194,39,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="215" Height="24" Foreground="White" x:Name="AuckBuildLoadStatTextBlock"/>
</Grid>
```

C# 2:

```
using Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry;
using System.Threading;
using Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Location;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Security;

namespace Scene_Layer_Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void LoadNewScene_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Uri bmUri = new Uri("http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer");
            ArcGISTiledLayer bmTLayer = new ArcGISTiledLayer(bmUri);
            Basemap bMap = new Basemap(bmTLayer);

            Scene newScene = new Scene(bMap);

            MapPoint mPt = new MapPoint(144.970782, -37.828037, 50000, SpatialReferences.Wgs84);
            Viewpoint vPt = new Viewpoint(mPt, 1);

            newScene.InitialViewpoint = vPt;

            newScene.LoadStatusChanged +=newScene_LoadStatusChanged;

            MySceneView.Scene = newScene;
        }

        void newScene_LoadStatusChanged(object sender, LoadStatusEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadStatusTextBlock.Text = e.Status.ToString();
        }

        public async void LoadAuckLayer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            //SceneServer LAS Uri
            Uri ssLasUri = new Uri("https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/*******/arcgis/rest/services/*****/SceneServer");

            ArcGISSceneLayer sfSceneLayer = new ArcGISSceneLayer(ssLasUri);
            sfSceneLayer.Name = "AuckBuild";

            sfSceneLayer.LoadStatusChanged += sfSceneLayer_LoadStatusChanged;

            await sfSceneLayer.LoadAsync();

            MySceneView.Scene.OperationalLayers.Add(sfSceneLayer);
        }

        void sfSceneLayer_LoadStatusChanged(object sender, LoadStatusEventArgs e)
        {
            AuckBuildLoadStatTextBlock.Text = e.Status.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use layer endpoint ("/layer/[id]")
For example:
http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/z2tnIkrLQ2BRzr6P/arcgis/rest/services/RiparianAfter/SceneServer/layers/0